error of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Stubs'
In VScode, I have the following file structure:

In profiler.py, I try to use "from Stubs.aaa import a'

But I met error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Stubs'"
Could anyone tell me why and how to solve it?Thank you.

From which directory are you running Python? Or perhaps, how are you running things? Or even, what are you running; are you running profiler.py directly? Because that's a bad idea, and shouldn't be done. Or is prof.profiler itself imported in another script?

Also, please note this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. Don't use images of code (including the directory structure). Use plain text and the code-block formatting tools in the inline editor for code and other fixed formatting (e.g., traceback error messages, or directory structures).

Yes, in prof directory, I run profiler.py, and i met error. No, the prof.profiler doesnot import in another script

Don't do that: you're running a module inside a package (either the prof package or the VisualOP package) as a script. Scripts should be created and run outside of any Python packages.

Related Q&A.

Please provide a complete catalog of your workspace.

Add at the top of the code
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/aaa")

Specifics and more methods require you to provide a complete workspace directory structure.
